# How to prevent browser back button from transitioning back to login page and logging user out on React-Router v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am having some trouble with the useNavigate function from React-Router v6. My main goal is to prevent the user from logging themselves out and returning to the home page, when pressing the browser back button.

The issue I am having is when the browser back button is pressed, my application treats that as a log out and returns to the login page. I would like to alter that so when the browser back button is pressed, the user is returned/remains on the homepage. A logout should only occur when the user manually logs themselves out, by selecting the logout button.

I believe I have set up my homepage useNavigate functions properly, yet as I am still learning the process, I may have missed a few things. Below is the code for the main pages in question: login page, home page and privateroutes.js (this function is what protects the private routes by checking is user is logged in).

Homepage.js

```
import { AppBar, Toolbar, IconButton, Typography, Box } from '@mui/material';
import { Menu } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { theme } from '../../App';
import { GeneratorComp } from '../../components/GeneratorComp/generatorcomp';


import './home.css';
import { SideMenu } from '../../components/SideMenu/sidemenu';

export function Home() {
    const location = useLocation();

    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };

    const handleDrawerClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Box component='nav' sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                    <AppBar position='static'>
                        <Toolbar>
                            <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerOpen} size='large'>
                                <Menu fontSize='large' sx={{color: 'white'}}/>
                            </IconButton>
                            <SideMenu open={open} onClose={handleDrawerClose}/>
                            <Typography variant='h4' sx={{ml: 2, mr: 2, flexGrow: 1, textAlign: {xs: 'center', sm: 'start'}}}>Welcome,  {location.state.user.username}</Typography>
                        </Toolbar>
                    </AppBar>
                </Box>
                <Box component='main'>
                    <Typography className="subhead-title" variant="h5" sx={{mt: 3}}>
                        Generate your passwords below!
                    </Typography>
                    <GeneratorComp theme={theme}/>
                </Box>
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
};
```

Login.js

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import { Box, AppBar, Toolbar, TextField, Typography, Button } from '@mui/material';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { theme } from '../../App'

export function Login() {

    const [loginUsername, setLoginUsername] = useState('');
    const [loginPassword, setLoginPassword] = useState('');

    const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState(false);
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({});
    
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();

    const login = async () => {
        await Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/login', {
            username: loginUsername, 
            password: loginPassword, 
        }).then((res) => {
            if (!res.data.message) {
                setLoginStatus(true);
                setUserInfo(res.data.result[0]);
            } else {
                document.getElementById('submitMessage').innerHTML = res.data.message;
                document.getElementById('submitMessage').style.color = 'red';
            }
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (loginStatus) {
            navigate('/home', {state: {status: loginStatus, user: userInfo}, replace: true} );
        };
        console.log(location.state);
    }, [navigate,loginStatus, userInfo, location]);

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Box sx={{display: 'flex', flexDirection:'column', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Box component='nav' sx={{ flexGrow: 1, margin: 0, width: '100%' }}>
                    <AppBar position='static'>
                        <Toolbar>
                            <Typography variant='h4'  sx={{display: {xs: 'none', sm:'block'}, flexGrow:1, textAlign:'start', letterSpacing: {xs: 'none', sm: '0.4em',md:'0.6em'}}}>Passwordinator</Typography>
                            <Button color='inherit' onClick={() => {navigate('/generator', {state: {status: loginStatus, user: userInfo}})}}>Generator</Button>
                            <Button color='inherit' onClick={() => {navigate('/signup', {state: {status: loginStatus, user: userInfo}})}}>Signup</Button>
                        </Toolbar>
                    </AppBar>
                </Box>
                <Box component='form' sx={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', width: '90%',maxWidth: '500px', m: 4}}>
                    <Typography variant='h2' color='#ffffff' sx={{mb: '70px'}}>Welcome Back!</Typography>
                    <TextField id="input" label="Username" variant="outlined" onChange={(e) => {setLoginUsername(e.target.value)}} sx={{mt: 2, mb: 2}}/>        
                    <TextField id="input" label="Password" variant="outlined" onChange={(e) => {setLoginPassword(e.target.value)}} sx={{mt: 2, mb: 10}}/>       
                </Box>
                <Button color='primary' variant='contained' size='large' onClick={login} sx={{mb:8}}>Login</Button>
                <Typography id='submitMessage' variant='h6' ></Typography>
            </Box>
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
};
```

privateroutes.js

```
import {Outlet, Navigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export const PrivateRoutes = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    console.log(location.state);
    
        return (
            location.state && location.state.status ? <Outlet replace/> : <Navigate to='/login' />
        );
}
```

Comment: Why is a back navigation treated as a "logout action"? *That's* the part that seems broken IMHO. Couldn't/shouldn't you just remove that behavior and let the back navigation work as normal/expected? Can you edit the post to include all the relevant code you are working with and have an issue using? See [mcve].

Comment: Maybe I did not clarify the issue well enough... what you just described is my main issue. I have no clue why my broswer back button is logging me out nor do I know how to fix the issue or how I even got it to that point.

Comment: Can you share the part of your code that logs users out? Try to edit the post to include all relevant code as part of a complete [mcve]. If possible, could you also try creating a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?